# jquery disabled

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a Jquery function like this:

```
$("#cittadinanza_nascita_label").keyup(function () {
    $(this).autocomplete({
        source: "/index/status/",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("# cittadinanza_nascita_label").val(ui.item.label);
            $("# cittadinanza_nascita").val(ui.item.value);                        
        }
    });                
});
```

making the auto complete state of birth on a form. The 'value' is stored in a hidden type. I wish that if the value of this was X, the field 'comune_nascita' is put on disabled.

A little help?

Comment: Oh man how do you manage spaces as you posted here in your code.

Comment: Your selectors aren't right, the hashes are separated from the id's?

Comment: Seeing how the HTML is structured would also be very helpful for determining a proper solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are getting at.

```
if ($("# cittadinanza_nascita").val() == X) {
    $ ("# cittadinanza_nascita").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
$ ("# cittadinanza_nascita_label"). Keyup(function () {
    $ (this).autocomplete({
    source: "/index /status /"
    minLength: 2,
    select: function (event, ui) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $("#cittadinanza_nascita_label").val(ui.item.label);
       $("#cittadinanza_nascita").val(ui.item.value);
       if ($("#cittadinanza_nascita").val() === 'x') {
         $("#comune_nascita").attr('disabled','disabled');
       }
    }});
});
```

Comment: solved with this: if (ui.item.value != '100000100') 
                                 $("#comune_nascita_label").prop('disabled', true);
                            else
                                $("#comune_nascita_label").prop('disabled', false);

Answer (score 0):

> The [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method should be used to set disabled and checked instead
>   of the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

```
if($("#cittadinanza_nascita_label").val() == "YOUR X VALUE"){
    $("#cittadinanza_nascita").prop('disabled', true);
}
```